# RichTextBox IsDocumentEnabled with InlineUIContainers

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, richtextbox, flowdocument

I'm creating a `RichTextBox` which contains various different `InlineUIContainer`s, but can't seem to get button click events within those containers to work.  If I set `IsDocumentEnabled = true` for the `RichTextBox`, then `BlockUIContainer` click events will work; however, `InlineUIContainer` click events still do not work.

Does anybody know if such functionality is possible?

EDIT: Adding a code example.

This works:

```
<RichTextBox IsDocumentEnabled="True">
    <FlowDocument>
        <BlockUIContainer>
            <Button Click="SomeEvent">
        </BlockUIContainer>
        <Paragraph>
            ... Some Content ...
        </Paragraph>
    </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
```

But this doesn't:

```
<RichTextBox IsDocumentEnabled="True">
    <FlowDocument>
        <Paragraph>
            <InlineUIContainer>
                <Button Click="SomeEvent" />
            </InlineUIContainer>
         </Paragraph>
    </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was wrapping them in a tag that had `IsHitTestVisible=true` set, but it wasn't terribly obvious.  Works great now.